# Jordan normal form in $n$-th root

Tags: linear-algebra, jordan-normal-form

How to find $\bigl(Jk(λ)\bigr)^n$ ($n \in\mathbb N)$. I've found the solution for $\lambda=0$. I need the look of matrix and the steps

Comment: Can you show us your efforts? Is $Jk(\lambda)$ a $k\times k$-matrix?

Comment: yes k×k. Solution for λ=0 is matrix with 1 on the top in n+1 position

Comment: If yes, note that $Jk(\lambda)=\lambda I+M$ and $IM=MI$, whereas $M$ is a matrix with 1 in the first upper subdiagonal and 0 else

Comment: can you please show the steps?

Answer (score 0):

We have $Jk(\lambda)=\lambda I+(Jk(\lambda)-\lambda I)$ and define $M=Jk(\lambda)-\lambda I$, then $I$ and $M$ are commuting. You can use binomial theorem to get
$$Jk(\lambda)^n=(\lambda I+M)^n=\sum_{j=0}^n\binom{n}{j}(\lambda I)^jM^{n-j}=\lambda^nI+\sum_{j=0}^{n-1}\binom{n}{j}(\lambda I)^jM^{n-j}$$
Maybe you should try to find out what happens for $k=3$ in the binomial theorem:
$$\left(\begin{pmatrix}\lambda &0 &0\\
0 &\lambda & 0\\
0 & 0 & \lambda  \end{pmatrix}+\begin{pmatrix}0 &1 &0\\
0 &0 & 1\\
0 & 0 & 0  \end{pmatrix}\right)^n=T$$
This is the sum of a diagonalizable ($\lambda I$) and a nilpotent ($M$) matrix.

The result is

> \begin{align}T=\begin{pmatrix}\lambda^n & \binom{n}{1}\lambda^{n-1} & \binom{n}{2}\lambda^{n-2}\\0 & \lambda^n & \binom{n}{1}\lambda^{n-1}\\ 0 & 0 & \lambda^n \end{pmatrix}\end{align}

Comment: thank you but how the matrix will look like?

Comment: Well you must calculate $M^{i}$ for $0\leq i\leq n-1$ and multiply it with a identity matrix, so this is very easy.

Comment: can you please still show how the matrix will look like?

Comment: You can find the answer in wikipedia

Comment: what are the key words to find?

Comment: a what will be the jordan normal form of $Jk(λ)^n$